# Laravel 5.5: Pegar nome de cada tabela no select union

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, union

Preciso fazer um *select* em duas tabelas e juntar elas com o `union`, até aí certo, mas preciso pegar também o nome das duas para poder identificar lá na `View`.

Já tentei utilizar o `getTable()` em cada *select*, mas me retorna o erro:

> `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getTable() should not be called statically`

Também tentei pegar direto no `select`, pois já fiz desse jeito uma vez sem usar o `Laravel`: `select('tabela1 as table')` e me retorna um erro de sintaxe.

Qual a forma correta de fazer isso?

***Código:***

```
$first = Lista::where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->select('descricao as result1');

$atividades = Avaliar::where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->select('nota as result1')
        ->union($first)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Você deseja pegar os nomes da tabelas no UNION? eu acabei não entendendo.?

Comment: Exato, pois vou precisar identificar elas na view.

Comment: Na `View` com assim??? se fala o arquivo blade?

Comment: Sim. Simplificando, digamos que os resultados vindo da tabela lista, ficarão na cor vermelha e os que vierem da tabela avaliar, ficarão na cor azul.

Comment: Entendi @Diego, e se for identificado na própria `SQL`?

Comment: Não entendi, como assim?

Comment: Eu posso identificar na própria SQL o nome da tabela de forma explicita!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70735/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-diego-vieira).

Comment: Teu exemplo ali funcionou bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na própria `SQL` crie a identificação de cada `SELECT`, ***exemplo***:

```
$first = Lista::where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->select('descricao as result1')
        ->selectRaw("'Lista' as tabela");

$atividades = Avaliar::where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->select('nota as result1')
        ->selectRaw("'Avaliar' as tabela");
        ->union($first)            
        ->get();
```